# Parent menu items in dropdown are not clickable

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I've got a dropdown menu on my Joomla 4 site, and the parent items in the 2nd level are not clickable for some reason. What would cause that?

Here is the site: https://qph.uim.temporary.site/

If you click on Products, every item in that list should take you to another page. Each of those menu items — even the parent ones — are of the type "Single Article". The only ones that work are "Get It Fast, Ship Today", "ProBox Apparel", and "ProBox Repair Kit" because those are not parent items.

You can see in the browser's status bar that the links are there, but it's like there's a preventDefault somewhere that's preventing it from following the link.

Comment: Removing data-bs-toggle="dropdown" from each menu item fixes it (thanks, Sharky), but I don't understand why in this case, since this version of the menu doesn't use any custom javascript, and I would think the dropdowns would work right out of the box.